GPIO Setup causing memory allocation error
I'm getting a memory allocation error when running a GPIO setup on my Raspberry Pi, for the purpose of running a servo.
I'd like to run the following code to set up the servo on my Raspberry Pi:
# Import libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Set GPIO numbering mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Set pin 11 as an output, and set servo1 as pin 11 as PWM
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
servo1 = GPIO.PWM(11,50) # Note 11 is pin, 50 = 50Hz pulse

Whenever I try to run this, I get the following error:
#malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted

The servo is brand-new, and I've rechecked the pin connections and they look good - any ideas to what's going on?

From https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/145064/problems-connecting-a-servo-to-raspberry-pi-5

The Pi5 uses different hardware to implement the GPIO. This different hardware is likely going to be used for all future Pi models. Existing established GPIO libraries such as wiringPi, RPi.GPIO, and pigpio were written for the earlier hardware and are unlikely ever to be rewritten to support the new GPIO hardware.

Are you using a PI5?

Yup - I used gpiozero rather than RPi.GPIO and it did the trick.

The best choice is to use libgpiod. It's native library to the Linux kernel. All those custom implementations are legacy which is not portable or usable in a good way.
